# WCF Error: Service too busy

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted in windows service.
When I try invoking the service from my client app I'm getting:

> The HTTP service located at xxx is too busy.

I tried changing the `maxConcurrentSessions` and `maxConcurrentCalls`, but the problem didn't go.

Any idea?

Comment: can you browse the service from client machine? @Itay.B

Comment: Have you checked the ID that its running under?  Sounds like the service either isn't starting, or is starting and then running into a loop of some kind

Comment: how many client did you connect?@Itay.B

Comment: @BlueChippy, how can i tell if it's running in a loop?

Comment: @Rezoan, 1 client. and when i test it from the wcfTestClient tool it's working good.

Comment: have you use fiddler before? @Itay.B

Comment: @Rezoan, Yes i did. What will i see in fiddler in this case?

Comment: yes can you see the raw request and response?@Itay.B

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40066/discussion-between-rezoan-and-itay-b)

Comment: you can check the service using logging and performance counters of some kind, from quick and dirty writing to a text file through to full diagnostics and performance counters.  Given that it seems to be OK in debug mode, but not when running as a service, I'd be more inclined to think it was permissions related.  Try adding something like log4net and writing out different stages of startup and any exceptions you catch...wrap the very highest level in a try/catch and log if it gets caught there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rezoan told me to do, I removed the  "Desing_Time_Address" from the service address (both in the host and in the client) and bammm...it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In order to diagnose the issue I would recommend enabling tracing in your WCF Service. The following link should hopefully help you walk through the process...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx